# How do I print this array in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

**I want to print the `description_expenses` and it`s respective description, and a `\n` for each expense. something like:**

Rent - 800$

Gym - 80$

' ' - 0$

$final after all your expenses

```
income_input = float(input("Please inform your income : R$ "))

expenses = []
sum_expenses = 0

while True:
    description_expenses = input("Describe your expense")
    description_expenses = description_expenses.upper()
    value_expenses = float(input(f"Type the value of your expense  {description_expenses} - $ "))
    expenses += description_expenses, value_expenses
    sum_expenses += value_expenses
    
    if description_expenses == '' or value_expenses == 0:
        break

final = (income_input - sum_gastos)

print(?????)

try:
    print(f"${final} after all your expenses.")
except:
    print("FINISH")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
income_input = float(input("Please inform your income : R$ "))

expenses = []
sum_expenses = 0

while True:
    description_expenses = input("Describe your expense: ")
    if not description_expenses:
        break

    expenses_value_input = input(
        f"Type the value of your expense  {description_expenses} - $ "
    )
    value_expenses = float(expenses_value_input if expenses_value_input else 0)
    if not value_expenses:
        break

    description_expenses = description_expenses.upper()
    expenses += description_expenses, value_expenses
    sum_expenses += value_expenses

# https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range.step
for i in range(0, len(expenses), 2):
    print(f"Expense: {expenses[i]} - $ {expenses[i + 1]}")

final = income_input - sum_expenses  # I corrected the variable name here

print(f"${final} after all your expenses.")
```

```
@ python income-input-array.py 
Please inform your income : R$ 1000
Describe your expense: rent
Type the value of your expense  rent - $ 100
Describe your expense: food
Type the value of your expense  food - $ 250
Describe your expense: 
Expense: RENT - $ 100.0
Expense: FOOD - $ 250.0
$650.0 after all your expenses.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `join` function:

```py
print("\n".join(f"{description} - {value}$" for description, value in expenses))
```